# Unlock Files for deletion

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cruisecontrol.net

I am automating testing with test complete and CCNet. I am getting the error message "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" while deleting some folders.

Is there any tools which can be used to unlock the file? I need to automate the unlock operation from CCnet

Comment: A process locks a file to prevent you from deleting it.  You'll need to find out why this process is still running and why it is using the file.  Using hacky tools just causes a very nasty kind of random file system corruption.  You've been asking these kind of questions for over a year, time you start owning the machine instead of the machine owning you.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried it myself but [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) might solve your problem. According to the [FAQ](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#faq) it has a CLI:

> - Can Unlocker be run in command line? Yes! Unlocker -H for command line options.

Comment: FYI, my AV detects Babylon toolbar in the Unlocker installer.

Comment: It looks like Unlocker installs spyware nowadays http://malwaretips.com/threads/unlocker-1-9-2.15924/

Answer (score -1):

Open task manager (ctrl + alt + del keys, select task manager), and see if you can find the name of your most recent application. If you find the application still running, but not visible, that means it switched to a background process, and likely has a bug/infinite loop. End the program task if you find it (you may very well find several) and that should clear up an file-IO errors. Hopefully this helped!